# Remove spacing between elements of recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made a news feed app and I have used recyclerview to show the images but there is a large gap between two images as shown in the screenshot below. I tried using the RecyclerView Item Decoration but it didn't work.I have also given the code of my feedFragment and feedAdapter.  Please help

[image]

feedFragment

```
package com.example.fireapp;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.fireapp.Adapter.feedAdapter;
import com.example.fireapp.model.Image;
import com.example.fireapp.model.Users;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class feedFragment extends Fragment {
    Button uploadButton;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 7;
    private Uri uri;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    String downloadUrl;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    feedAdapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed,container,false);
        //upload image
        uploadButton=view.findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        //save image to database
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        //setup recycler view
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new feedAdapter(images, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //get the latest images
        Query imagesQuery = reference.child("Feed_Images").orderByKey().limitToFirst(100);
        imagesQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                final Image image = dataSnapshot.getValue(Image.class);

                //get the image user
                reference.child("User/"+image.userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        image.user = user;
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                mAdapter.addImage(image);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return  view;
    }

    //get extension of file
    public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));

    }

    //select image
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            uri = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (uri != null) {
                //this is for image file name
                storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Feed_Image");
                final StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() +
                        "." + GetFileExtension(uri));
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos);
                byte[] dataa = baos.toByteArray();

                UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(dataa);
                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                downloadUrl=uri.toString();
                                String key=reference.child("Feed_Images").push().getKey();
                                Image image = new Image(key,mUser.getUid(),downloadUrl);
                                reference.child("Feed_Images").child(key).setValue(image);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //Toast.makeText(accountActivity.this, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }


}
```

feedAdapter

```
package com.example.fireapp.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.fireapp.R;
import com.example.fireapp.feedFragment;
import com.example.fireapp.model.Image;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class feedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<feedAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Image> mDataset;
    private feedFragment mfeedFragment;


    public feedAdapter(ArrayList<Image> myDataset, feedFragment feedFragment) {
        mDataset=myDataset;
        mfeedFragment=feedFragment;
    }



    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public Button mLikeButton;


        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            mTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mLikeButton=v.findViewById(R.id.likeButton);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public feedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_image,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull feedAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Image image = mDataset.get(position);
        if (image.user != null) {
            holder.mTextView.setText(image.user.username);
        }
        Picasso.get().load(image.downloadUrl).fit().into(holder.mImageView);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
    public void addImage(Image image){
        mDataset.add(0,image);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

feed_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="246dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="sample text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/likeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Like" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just a screenshot is not sufficient to determine why the gap occurs. please provide some code.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: You must set the height of your items, equal to wrap_content not match_parent

Comment: Its set to wrap_content. There is no gap until I scroll down. After I scroll down or up the large gap forms

Comment: Can you share the code for your layout, R.layout.feed_image?

This might not be relevant, but I'm not sure why you're passing the feedFragment into the adapter. It doesn't look like you're using it, and that is not a good practice.

Comment: added the xml file and I am using the feedFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

instead of

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
```